# Autoincremental auxiliar index var for XQuery nested loops

Tags: xml, loops, xpath, for-loop, xquery

I´m trying to hold the iteration number in vars, but as you know, xQuery vars are immutable

There´s an special syntax like

```
for $film at $i in doc('films.xml')/films/film
return <film>{$i}.{data($film/@title)}</film>
```

My problem is, how to hold the value of the absolute iteration when a loop is inside another loop.

```
for $film at $i in doc('films.xml')/films/film
for $goofs at $j in $film/goofs/goof
return **total_absolute_number_goof**
```

I mean I dont need

```
i=1 j=1,2,3            i=1 j=1,2,3
i=2 j=1,2,3...  but    i=2 j=4,5,6
```

Is there any easy way to achieve that in xquery?

EDIT: java equivalent

```
int j = 0;
for (;some_external_condition;) 
   for (;some_external_condition;j++) {}
//j would print number of total iterations
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a feature in XQuery 3.0 to do this:

```
for $film at $i in doc('films.xml')/films/film
for $goofs at $j in $film/goofs/goof
count $k
return $k
```

It's already been added to some XQuery processors, for example Saxon-EE 9.4.

In XQuery 1.0 I think you would need two passes: first create the list of films, then number them.

Comment: You are awesome Michael! Basically you are XML itself xD

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could not use XQuery 3.0 count function, so I had to do this:

```
    declare variable $array := ('a','b','c');
    declare variable $array2 := ('*','>',')');

    for $a at $c in $array
    for $b at $d in $array
    let $absIter := (($c - 1) * count($array)) + $d
    return $absIter
```

Prints:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

But it grows exponentially complex though...

```
    declare variable $array := ('a','b','c');
    declare variable $array2 := ('*','>');
    declare variable $array3 := ('*','>',')','ä');

    for $a at $d in $array
    for $b at $e in $array2
    for $c at $f in $array3
    let $absIter := (($d - 1) * count($array3) * count($array2)) + (($e - 1) * count($array3)) + $f
    return $absIter
```

Prints:

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
```

The problem is when the number of iterations in a subloop is not always the same (i.e, a dynamic subselect from a var in the parent loop) -> 
[Autoincremental auxiliar index var for XQuery nested loops (w. dynamical count)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311618/autoincremental-auxiliar-index-var-for-xquery-nested-loops-w-dynamical-count)