# Autoincremental auxiliar index var for XQuery nested loops (w. dynamical count)

Tags: xml, loops, iteration, xquery, counter

I want a solution for udnerstanding how to hold a real loop counter as Java in xQuery, not a workaround for my particular simplified demo. I know in xQuery 3.0 there is a count reserved word for FLOWR structures but its useless pre-Saxon 9.something. Here my example.

```
     for $elem at $x in /Data/* return element Elem {       
            attribute Name   {concat('_',$x,'.',name($elem))},      
            (: ...10 lines of code... :)        
            for $subelem at $y in $elem/*       
            (: ...5 lets... :)      
            return element SubElemen {
               attribute Name {concat('_',$x,'.',$y,'_',name($subelement))},
               (...20 lines of other attrs and elements ...)
           for $subsubelem at $z in $subElem/SubSubElement
               let $absIterIndex := 'THIS IS WHAT IM LOOKING'
               let $subSubElemName := concat('_',$absIterIndex,'_',name($subElem))
            return
                                 element SubSubElem {
                 attribute Name {$subsubelem}, 
                   (..100 lines more playing with $x, $y, $absIterIndex, all lets for that iteration, attributes depending on them...)
```

The output is something like this (real data hidden and simplified)

```
 <Elem Name="_1.Name">
      <SubElem Name="_1.1_Name">
           <SubSubElem Name="_1.First"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_2.Second"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_3.Third"/>
      </SubElem Name="_1.1_Name">
      <SubElem Name="_1.2_Name">
           <SubSubElem Name="_4.Fourth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_5.Fifth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_6.Sixth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_7.Seventh"/>
      </SubElem Name="_1.1_Name">
  <Elem Name="_2.Name">
      <SubElem Name="_2.1_Name">
           <SubSubElem Name="_8.Eighth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_9.Ninth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_10.Tenth"/>
           <SubSubElem Name="_11.Eleventh"/>
      </SubElem Name="_2.1_Name">
      <SubElem Name="_2.2_Name"/>
  </Elem Name="_2.Name">
  <Elem Name="_3.Name">
      <SubElem Name="_3.1_Name">
           <SubSubElem Name="_12.Twelven"/>
      </SubElem Name="_3.1_Name">
      <SubElem Name="_3.2_Name"/>
  </Elem Name="_3.Name">
```

This is a extension of a previous question [Autoincremental auxiliar index var for XQuery nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135635/autoincremental-auxiliar-index-var-for-xquery-nested-loops), which I accepted the solution for the xQuery 3.0 counter, and then propose an alternative for manually doing it. But know i think the perspective is different and more concrete, and with a new example. If you think it should be deleted just tell it to me.

Comment: This question is quite vague -- please edit the question and provide a *complete* (but as small as possible) example: XML document, exact wanted result, requirements that the query must implement.

Comment: I make a whole example just for announcing the problem, and I think its great, but my problem is probably english because its not my primary language sorry. Ill try my best

Comment: user1352530: I could help you if the problem were *concrete* -- as it is it is generall and one has to do a lot of guessing (and have little confidence of the correctness of this guessing) in building a demo example to show the technique.

Comment: I just need to get that line with $lettersTotal. It should contain the current total accumulated letters in every iteration, so along with the return the app would print 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... nº total letters/iterations

Comment: user1352530: I find this problem not at all illustrative of the actual problem you want to express -- this specific problem has a very simple solution -- just output the numbers 1 to N, where N is the count of all non-whitespace characters.

Comment: But this is a simplification and a demo I need. The question is I do need to fill that variable and I ask if there is any way to get filled it with the actual iteration in order to work with it after. The original query is 150 lines to put it here. I improved the code to put a more fitted example

Comment: As you see, this "demo" is oversimplified and doesn't provide us any definition of the problem. I still am not sure what you actually want. The fact that you don't have a representative example may mean that you don't have a clear understanding what the problem is. To put it in another way: A "problem" non-existing specific example is not a problem.

Comment: I think its easier than it seems at least from the example. I have three nested loops. I need to keep (in a var inside the last one) the number of the total absolute iterations accumulated at any given iteration. The clue is in the return now after I edited the answer, print iteration plus letter, so you need the counter inside the loops and it needs to be updated for any iteration

Comment: My last attempt to rewrite it properly :)

Comment: This last edit clearly shows what you want and the fact that you want something doesn't mean at all that any problem exists for solving which the wanted feature is necessary. I am now more convinced that the question isn't based on any real problem. My prediction is that any problem you show to us in support of the wanted feature, will have a solution without this feature. But it is up to you to prove me wrong :)

Comment: thank you for your patience! But also we need to think that in case we wanted to print the letter plus the position (current code), is a real problem that should be solved I think keeping the kind of solution Im looking for (i.e counter).

Comment: Your right in the updated answer, man. I cannot found a practical example which is not totally abstract and cannot be resolved by count-ing the total but I promise it is possible !! Jsut imagine $line, $word and $letter are given arrays, not related between them and loaded fom outside

Comment: user1352530: I cannot "just imagine". Thanks God, I am an atheist. :) I will take this "problem" seriously, the moment you provide a specific problem that doesn't have a solution, except using the wanted feature.

Comment: Ok, wait for it soon or later but today i will find a proper example

Comment: user1352530: Rest assured that I will be appreciative of such an outcome.

Comment: I accepted Gunthers answer. I give up. I understand put it all in a for loop and put code in return for any iteration so I will have to move the logic and more than 30 lines of code in a unique return ... :ß( Thanks for your help!

Comment: user1352530: So, we have a proof that this is actually not a problem but a request for a unnecessary feature.

Comment: OK. Now I put my original code rewritten. Youll see Im building a whole tree dynamically so I need to put thinggs during the iteration. I hope you still no think this is not a real problem and can intuitively solved without counters :)

Comment: user1352530: Could you, please, edit the question and provide the source XML document as well? Now it is difficult to understand what the query is doing. I'll have a look as soon as the question becomes clear.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but i dont think i can put all the real example because its from an important company... I only can put this demo versions, and if i could not expose the problem so far, i think i cannot do it better! No worry, thank you for your help

Comment: user1352530: @Gunther gave you a solution that doesn't require "counters" -- therefore you still haven't shown a problem that really requires such a feature. Even more evidence that such a feature isn't needed at all. As for not providing company data -- you are absolutely right -- please, give us non-company data -- shouldn't be difficult :)

Comment: user1352530: And of course, the provided query doesn't even compile ...

Comment: of course, you ask me for putting the real code, and that does not work. If it did, I wont be here asking :). Furthermore its a 150 lines code...  and its the third time I post a brand new demo, I think you can get the idea with this one. I dont think its necessary goign so far for asking how the hell imitate the behaviour of a counter inside 3 loops... but I really appreciate your help and patience. If you put closing brackets at the end it should work but i did not test it

Comment: user1352530: Now you are seeking an excuse not to provide a problem that can only be solved using the newly proposed "feature". It is *your* task to show us such a problem -- not ours. So far you haven't done this, and every consecutive failure to provide such a problem confirms with even greater certainty that such a feature is unnecessary -- how do the physiscists call this -- sigma 5? :)

Comment: I am not showing a problem. I put an example and I said clearly that i didnt need a workaround (i.e dont mind i f a count-letter() function exist). I only wanted to know how to fill a var with the iteration of that loop inside the loops itself if possible in the traditional languages way. Such feature is not unnecessary because if it wasnt "count" reserved word had not appeared in xquery 3.0 so parsers like Saxon use it... OOP could also be considered innecessary..

Comment: user1352530: What *you* term "workaround" is the actual solution. The proposed feature is unnecessary, because there hasn't been shown even a single problem that can only be solved with that feature.

Comment: My problem was knowing how to populate a counter inside a loop, not to count letters or getting actually an alternative solution (but I appreciate approaches anyway)!

Comment: user1352530: This may be *your* problem, but this isn't XQuery or XSLT or any other FP language problem -- therefore isn't appropriate for any of these SO tags.

Comment: Exactly, its my problem to know if there is a way to use a tool ive been using all life in java, c, javascript, visual basic. If its not necessary why the hell did they provided in the third revision of a language? Because there was real need for this... I think the tags serve as an orientation for describing the question, not for blaming whos the fault

Comment: user1352530: Anyone who starts using a functional programming language needs to get rid of the remnants of the imperative programming world such as counters and to get accustomed to the fact that the world doesn't cease to exist without these remnants -- or as some call this -- a "paradigm shift" or a "aha moment". It's time to break the imperative programming chains and to enlarge one's horizons.

Comment: why did they put a counter then?

Comment: user1352530: That's a good question -- I am interested to see their use-case. My guess is that they wanted to make things "easier" for some people. This doesn't change the fact that any problem can be solved without using this new feature.

Comment: Then u are answering yourself... I think that make things easier is a "need". And if that need has been implemented is because is more "needed" than any of the thousand things are not needed. OOP is neither need it in that sense. We could all develope in assembler, so u can do EVERYTHING. The rest is not needed. No pun intended.

Comment: user1352530: XPath 2.0, XSLT 2.0 and XQuery are rather too far from Assembler :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New question - new answer.

But the principle remains the same: produce an unnumbered result first, then apply the numbering. This may require rewriting the result.

Insert your code instead of the XML comment below.

```
declare function local:renumber($number, $string)
{
  replace($string, 'THIS IS WHAT IM LOOKING', string($number))
};

declare function local:renumber($subSubElems, $number, $nodes)
{
  for $node in $nodes
  return
    typeswitch ($node)
    case attribute()              return attribute {node-name($node)} {local:renumber($number, $node)}
    case processing-instruction() return processing-instruction {name($node)} {local:renumber($number, $node)}
    case comment()                return comment {local:renumber($number, $node)}
    case text()                   return text {local:renumber($number, $node)}
    default (: element() :) return
      element {node-name($node)}
      {
        local:renumber
        (
          $subSubElems, 
          if ($subSubElems[. is $node]) then count($subSubElems[. << $node]) + 1 else $number, 
          ($node/@*, $node/node())
        )
      }
};

let $result := <result>{<!-- your code here -->}</result>
return local:renumber($result//SubSubElem, 0, $result/node())
```

Comment: wow, as a alternative solution it can work well. Thanks!! I will use this as longs as there is no better easier counter option!

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is add an extra pass over the result sequence of your nested iterations, i.e.

```
declare variable $script := 'abc defg h ijklm nop 
                                 qrs tu vw
                                 xy z';
for $letter at $lettersTotal in
(
  for $line at $numLine in tokenize($script, '(\r\n?|\n\r?)')
  for $word at $numWord in tokenize(normalize-space($line),' ')
  for $codepoint at $numLetter in string-to-codepoints($word)
  return codepoints-to-string($codepoint)
)
return ($lettersTotal, $letter)
```

This returns

```
1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f 7 g 8 h 9 i 10 j 11 k 12 l 13 m 14 n 15 o 16 p 17 q 18 r 19 s 20 t 21 u 22 v 23 w 24 x 25 y 26 z
```

If you are lucky, your XQuery processor can stream the result without materializing the sequence.

Comment: This is a very nice idea! But It has an important drawback. You cannot use the counter inside the current iteration, that is the 90% of uses. This one will be like passing it to a count(). Thank you!

Comment: OK, so replace the outer return clause by `return concat($lettersTotal, "º is ", $letter, ",")`. For a single result string, wrap the complete expression in `string-join(` and `, " ")`. This will get you what you want.

Comment: Thank you im sorry for my bad explanations, but is there some way to do it from inside the loop. Like if i wanted to print it every time from the last loop: 1a, 1a 2b, 1a 2b 3c... as example

Comment: No, there is no such feature.